# Transform transaction dataset for association rules spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I have transaction dataset which I'm preparing by

```
val df = spark.read.parquet("..").select("bill","plu_id").distinct()


| bill| plu_id|  
+-----+-------+  
|    1|3447284|  
|    1|3255517|  
|    1|   3757|  
|    1|3501662|  
|    1|  21676|  
|    2|3499538|  
|    2|3248365|  
|    2|3453599|  
|    2|3602083|  
|    2|  18898|  
|    3|3446809|  
+-----+-------+
```

Previously I have used PySpark

```
from pyspark.mllib.fpm import FPGrowth
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.read.parquet('..').select('bill','plu_id').distinct().cache()
datardd=df.rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1])).groupByKey().mapValues(list).values()
model = FPGrowth.train(datardd, minSupport=0.0001,  numPartitions=1024)
```

Could you please help me, how to prepare dataset for Association Rules model on **scala**? :)

Comment: Hey welcome to stackoverflow .  i'm not able to get what exactly u r trying to mean 
" get data where "bill" is bill id, and "plu_id" is id of the product. "bill" is unique and "plu_id" is unique per bill "    

can you please explain it bit more clear ?

Comment: I'm explaining structure of the data I have. product id is unique per bill